# TPS55165Q1 does not work in boost mode

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, 12v, texas-instruments, step-up

I need a power supply that delivers 12v with an input between 8v and 35v. That's the reason I bought a couple of TPS55165Q1 from Texas instruments. I've made 3 different PCBs with a similar circuit. All of them works great in buck mode, delivering 12v up to 500mA. When I change to boost mode, It does not deliver neither the current or voltage it was calculated. 
When I switch to low-power mode, it works just as expected in buck and boost mode. That's why I conclude that there is a protection thats working (in Low Power mode, all protections are disabled). 
I've tried to emulate as close as possible the circuit of Figure 3 of its evaluation board: http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slvuay1/slvuay1.pdf

I show you

[image: schematic][image]

I've chosen SRU1048-4R7 inductor from Digikey and take special care of its Rdc and peak current. All capacitors are ceramic except for the 100uF. Can you give me some advice in order to get it work? 
Thanks!

** EDIT **
I attach some oscillograms. It was taken with a Vin of 14.8v (Step-up mode)
[image: measurement of time]
[image: measurement of voltage]

Comment: Please explain _"When I change to boost mode", "When I switch to low-power mode"_. What do you do? Be specific.

Comment: Hi winny. The module has to switch automatically between buck and boost mode depending on its supply voltage. So if I just simply power up the supply with a voltage above 15v (aprox) it will work in buck mode. Below this value, it works in boost mode.
To switch to low-power mode, the PS pin does the job. When I power up the circuit with PS connected to main supply, It works in low power mode.

Comment: So you lowered the voltage? At what point did what happen? Show oscillograms. Main supply? You mean Vin?

Comment: I edited my question with oscillograms. Yes I lowered the voltage to 14.8v so the step-up mode starts. Yes, sorry for my bad english: Main supply = Vin

Comment: Why would the converter step _up_ 14.8 V to 12 V? Does not make sense. What does your oscillograms show? What's the problem?

Comment: TPS55165 is a continuous power supply. It has to deliver 12v with a vin from 5v to 35v. It has to switch automatically. You can't step down from, for example, 13v to 12v. That's is because the voltage difference between this values is too low. That's why the device enters in step up mode and that's where it does not work. The oscillogram show when the device is in step up mode. It seems that there is a protection enabled, because there is no way that a 2Mhz circuit has a ripple of 4khz

Comment: Then why did you say the transition occurs at 14.8 V? Please show with an oscillogram how it misbehaves during said transition. It's far from clear at the moment. 4 kHz is a "popular" LC output filter resonance frequency. Is it internally compensated? Are you staying within the limits for C and L according to the datasheet of the IC?